# Por que é necessário fechar arquivo?

Tags: java, arquivo, dispose

Por que é necessário essa linha em Java?

```
fout.close();
```

Contexto:

```
LinkedList values = new LinkedList(classe.getTurma().values());

    if (!values.isEmpty()) {

        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        String FILE = "TURMA";
        try {
            fout = new FileOutputStream(FILE);
            System.out.println("Tamanhno tuma" + values.size());
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
            oos.writeObject(values);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Sistema.class
                    .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Sistema.class
                    .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                fout.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Sistema.class
                        .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: De onde você tirou esse trecho? Adicione um exemplo, senão fica dificil entender o problema.

Comment: Acho que o que ele esta querendo saber é porque é necessário fechar arquivos como um todo, não em um aplicação especifica, se for isso é por causa que um arquivo aberto ira ocupar espaço desnecessário na memoria, e por isso é importante fechar arquivos apos o uso. Já tive um problema onde esqueci de fechar a requisição com um banco e por conta disso sofria com estouro de memoria.

Comment: coloquei o trecho em baixo

Comment: @Javinha Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 13):

Pode ser por várias razões:

- Uma delas é fazer a gravação se efetivar. Tem vários modos de manipulação de arquivos que só jogam no disco se precisar mesmo ou quando fechar. Então sem fechar não é gravado.
- Se deixar que o sistema operacional se encarregue de fechar quando o processo que o detém se encerra pode não só não gravar tudo o que precisa, mas pode gravar o que não devia.
- Pode ser porque o arquivo precisa ser usado por outro processo e precisa estar fechado para isso ser possível. A não ser que o arquivo estava compartilhado.
- O arquivo aberto ocupa recursos do sistema operacional, como manipuladores, memória e precisa de alguns mecanismo lidar com aquilo. O consumo de memória em parte é "cobrado" da sua aplicação, o que pode criar complicações se usar demais.

Pelo exemplo da pergunta postado depois, acho que só o segundo item não se aplica, ele é mais raro mesmo. Só note que os 3 `catch`es fazem a mesma coisa e é redundante fazer assim, dá para simplificar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

O `close()` em qualquer linguagem de programação e sistema operacional se usa basicamente para:

1. Se o sistema operacional tiver recursos limitados, por exemplo o 
   número de arquivos abertos em processadores de sistemas embarcados, você está desperdiçando recursos do sistema se nao fechar os arquivos com o `close()`.
2. Se o arquivo tiver qualquer tipo de buffer por trás dele e você não
   fazer um `close()` você pode perder dados.